How to integrate Camunda Modeler into an Android Mobile app?
I'm working on an Android mobile app that's supposed to model business processes in BPMN notation.
Does anyone know of a way to integrate Camunda Modeler into my mobile app, or any other way to access Camunda Modeler directly in my mobile application?
I'd like users to be able to model business processes directly on their phone's interface (ideally locally without connecting to the internet).
I've tried this approach:
I've accessed Camunda's API and interacted with it via a web app to be able to create business processes and automate them, but I've no idea how to go further and integrate my web app into my mobile app.
I don't know if this is the right approach.
I really need help with my project.
Can anyone suggest a better approach?
(Notice that I development my app using Kotlin and Jetpack Compose)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can't integrate the Camunda Desktop modeler in your Android app, but you can embed its underlying technology, https://bpmn.io/, and customize it to suit your needs.
See https://bpmn.io/toolkit/bpmn-js/walkthrough/.
